# Best way to set header title from a functional component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a functional component and I want to set the header title from the inside, while still being able to pass a function from inside the component as a parameter to the header.

The component is in a StackNavigator.

```
const generateStackOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps}: any) => NavigationScreenOptions = ({
    navigation,
    screenProps
}: any): NavigationScreenOptions => {
    const title :any = navigation.getParam("title", null);
    return {
        title
    };
};

const stackNavigatorConfig: StackNavigatorConfig = {
    initialRouteName: Routes.Info,
    navigationOptions: generateStackOptions
};

export const stackNavigator: NavigationContainer = createStackNavigator(stackRoutes, stackNavigatorConfig);
```

This approach does not work:

```
const Info: NavigationScreenComponent = (props: Props) => {
    const data = [];
    const myFunctionIDefineHere = () => {
      // Populates the data. This function should be called from a button in the header.
    }
    Info.navigationOptions = {
        title: "This is the information page"
    }
};
```

When the navigator accesses the navigationOptions it is still empty / undefined.

This approach however, does work:

```
const Info: NavigationScreenComponent = (props: Props) => {
   const data = [];
   const myFunctionIDefineHere = () => {
      // Populates the data. This function should be called from a button in the header.
   }
};

Info.navigationOptions = {
    title: "This is the information page"
};
```

But there is a function inside the component I cannot access now, which I need to add to the header. What's the best approach to this?

Comment: "But there is a function inside the component I cannot access now" what function? What does it do? How does your `Info` component get it? Please provide complete usecase because now it looks like [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Anyway you could have `navigationOptions` to be a function [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#using-params-in-the-title) that has access to `navigation` and its params.

Comment: I want to add the function to the onPress of a button I will put in the header. It does an async call.

I have tried defining the navigationOptions as a function, which returns an object with the title in it. But this approach doesn't work either since the same problem applies here. When accessed by the navigator, it is undefined.

Comment: Did you check whether the `generateStackOptions` function is getting called and its returning value?

Comment: Yes it does get called. The value of the returned title however, is null (the fallback value).

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like this:

```
const Info: NavigationScreenComponent = (props: Props) => {
   const data = [];
   const myFunctionIDefineHere = () => {
     // Populates the data. This function should be called from a button in    the header.
   }
   props.navigation.setParams({titleParam: "Your new text"});

};  

Info.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
  title: screenProps.navigation.getParam("titleParam", "You title text")
});
```

I believe it's possible;e to pass a function as well.